# How can I set a fixed custom password in Teamviewer (server) without sending registration data?

Tags: passwords, teamviewer

I use often **TeamViewer** both for Windows and Linux (sometimes even for other platforms, like Android)
As long as ID does not change between Teamviewer reopenings, it would be useful to define a **permanent password** so I can connect remotely.
But the program seems to require some kind of **registration**, and I am a bit of a privacy fanatic.

Does anyone know how could I set a fixed (between reboots) password without registering?

P.S: The command:

```
teamviewer --passwd [PASSWD]
```

would be fantastic, but *it does not work at all* (tested on Ubuntu and Kali, and Windows seems not to have it as for today, on March 2014): the Teamviewer windows simply does not open. If someone knows how to make it work, please tell me, I would prefer it.

Comment: Teamviewer has to work through their central system in order to find the computer to control anyway--while there may not be an official registration they have to know.  Why not just get a free e-mail account somewhere and use that to register?

Comment: Mostly for faster configuring the TeamViewer server itself. Sometimes I want to do this on a network with dozens of computers, so I will gain some time. For the rest, you are right, @LorenPechtel, they could know much more than they are supposed to know. I think the future will confirm us details about our privacy with remote control programs that will scare us (Snowden showed us some examples, didn't he?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow **these steps** (tested with v9 and v10):

1. Press the **pencil icon** (below the password and ID assigned).
2. Press "Next".
3. Input your **password** (twice).
4. Press "Next".
5. On the next (registration) screen simply press **"Cancel"**.

You will now see a **hidden password** beside the pencil. Your custom password is now **stored** and Teamviewer will always accept it, but (supposedly) you did **not send any registration** data.

Tested working on **Linux and Windows**. I suppose will work on most of the other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

The

> teamviewer --passwd [PASSWD]

actually is normal that it doesn't show any window. It will just start the teamviewer daemon in the background waiting for connections (or if it is already started it will make it restart) since it's used to start the program over SSH and simillar where you don't necessarily have a display. Try checking with

> ps ax | grep teamviewer

and you should see it's instance running after the command (or if it was already running you'll see it with a changed PID).

Comment: No, it does not. You are right: the daemon changes PID. But I can not connect; just like if there were no Teamviewer program (server) listening or opened. I have tested it on Ubuntu and Kali. I did open a thread on AskUbuntu (since it is more appropriate) here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425494/teamviewer-not-starting-from-command-line-when-using-passwd-switch

Answer (score 0):

One can set a **Personal password** which means you can connect to that machine using the machine's ID and that password.

This can be set by bringing up the preferences in TeamViewer and going to the Security section - you may need to scroll down but you can set the 'Personal password' there (Depending on your system there may be some variations see [here](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/3317/setup-permanent-password-on-client-withteamviewer-12)). If you enable '*Start TeamViewer with System*' (on the main screen under Unattended Access) then it will be possible to login again after a restart. The 'Grant easy access' option requires that you setup a [free] account.