# Connecting with Teamviewer

Tags: windows, passwords, teamviewer

I set up a teamviewer account earlier today because at work I have 2 screens and was thinking of playing hearthstone while working, because my work is boring as hell. Anyway I set up an account and my PC within it but when it asked me to set a password for the PC I left it blank, and now it asks for a password when I try to connect?

Comment: Check if this answer http://superuser.com/a/743149/183349 serves your purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a fixed custom password in Teamviewer (server) without sending registration data?](http://superuser.com/questions/720784/how-can-i-set-a-fixed-custom-password-in-teamviewer-server-without-sending-reg)

Answer (score 1):

Your home PC's Teamviewer is showing a one-time password that you have to provide your work PC's Teamviewer.

It shoud be in the section labeled (on your home PC) Allow Remote Connection and it'll be the Password field just beneath the Your ID field. Typically it's a 4-digit numerical value e.g. 1234

Comment: So basically I need to be at home to get that password\

Comment: Yes.If you had fully set up your home Teamviewer account, you could have done it all from work.